# A complex number and it's conjugate are a solution to an equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been trying to solve this question for a few hours but I'm stumped, any guidance would be appreciated

If $\gamma$ and $\bar{\gamma}$ are solutions to $z^2+az+b=0$ And $\gamma$ is not real then a,b are real

Another question of the same vein

If $\gamma$ and $\bar{\gamma}$ are solutions to $z^3+az^2+bz +c=0$ And $\gamma$ is not real then a,b and c are real

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gamma$ and $\overline{\gamma}$ are solutions of $z^2+az+b=0$, then the polynomial factorizes in $z^2+az+b=(z-\gamma)\cdot(z-\overline\gamma)=z^2-(\gamma+\overline\gamma)z+\gamma\overline\gamma=z^2-2Re(\gamma)z+|\gamma|^2$.

So $a$ and $b$ are reals.

The other question works the same.

**HINT:** You know that the third root of the polynomial must be real, factorize and apply the previous result.

Comment: Nice solution. There is one typo, there should be a $z$ after $2Re(\gamma)$.

Comment: Oh, it's true! I´m going to correct it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, just noticed that γγ¯=|γ|2, so it needs to be squared in you answer

Comment: True again, thanks! Corrected